# How can I start a WAMP and MySQL on the same computer?

Tags: mysql, port, wamp

I am creating a web page for my WoW server. If I start a WAMP and then open the web page, there is an error shown in the upper left corner:

> Error: Unable to connect to MySQL server. MySQL reported: Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
>   Notice: Undefined index: off in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 569

I tried to run MySQL, but the problem is that it won't start because it tries to run from the same port as the WAMP (both are port 3306).

What can I do to get MySQL and the WAMP started on the same computer?

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SuperUser. Please read the [FAQ] to learn how to edit your question appropriately, as it is not understandable in its current form.

Comment: If you have already installed WAMP, there is no need to run MySQL separately - it is already included in WAMP. The error message clearly states that your password is incorrect, which means that MySQL is already running. So, instead of starting MySQL, you access it through a client such as phpmyadmin and set the root password.

Comment: @PrahladYeri - You should make that comment the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, If you have already installed WAMP, there is no need to run MySQL separately - it is already included in WAMP - The M stands for MySQL.

The error message clearly states that your password is incorrect, which means that MySQL is already running. So, instead of starting MySQL, you access it through a client such as phpmyadmin and set the root password. MySQL Workbench is another client which is Windows based.